# Upgrading hosting plan for an existing Django app on shared hosting

Tags: django

So I'm currently running the OSQA (Django) app on my site, and it currently uses shared hosting on DreamHost. How would I go about transferring my site to a..lets say..dedicated server? Would I have to install everything all over (Python, django etc)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've hosted Django on a dedicated server ([Linode](http://linode.com)), and yes, you do have to install Python, Django, and any other software you're using. A well maintained pip requirements file, fabric, and source control with git and github make things easier.

Unless you have a specific requirement for a dedicated server you may be happier with a platform as service provider, since they handle a lot of the configuration and deployment work for you and let you deploy directly from source control. Most offer free plans. I've had luck with [Heroku](http://heroku.com) and heard good things about [Appfog](http://www.appfog.com/). This Quora response offers other alternatives: http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Heroku-equivalent-for-Django-applications